# Given python function object, produce list of other functions used

Tags: python, introspection

## Background

I am working in the area of nonlinear optimization and I have an expensive cost function.  The cost function involves some embarrassingly parallel code that I want to distribute across multiple python processes to escape the GIL.  Because these are separate processes, they do not inherit the global namespace / imports from the "core" process.

My core process utilizes some imports that take quite a long time (up to 1s) to complete.  The typical solution to this is to migrate the required imports into the body of the parallelized function.  Because it is ugly, I would like to forego it in exchange for some far uglier behind the scenes magic to handle imports.  I also want to avoid creating a new worker pool with each cost function evaluation to avoid waste (up to 40% of my parallel implementation's execute time is process spinup and import).

I have created a small library that allows me to `map` a set of function calls across any number of long-lived workers, and discard/kill them after all iterations of the cost function have been evaluated.  This gives me some flexibility vs the `multiprocessing` library's `Pool`s or `Pathos`.

## The task

suppose I have some file:

```
optimizer.py

from mymodule import a,b,c
def cost_function(parameters):
    p = parameters
    pt1 = a(p[0])
    pt2 = b(pt1, p[1])
    pt3 = c(pt2, p[2])
    return pt3.results # looks like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]
```

given the `cost_function` object, is there a way to build a list of all of the functions called inside of it, without executing it?

The list including builtins, etc, is fine.  It is relatively easy to iterate over the list of returned functions and filter out builtins, and also to locate the source (where to `import`) from given the function name.

---

edit: below is the code I use to spawn worker processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def spawn_workers(self, num_workers):
        for i in range(num_workers):
            Process(target=worker_fcn, kwargs=dict(config_dict=self.cfg)).start()
```

`self` refers to a class instance that holds some configuration information.

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just leave the imports outside the function? (And are your workers spawned by forking or from scratch?)

Comment: @user2357112 the workers are spawned by `multiprocessing.Process(target=fcn, kwargs={...}).start()` -- they will not inherit the global namespace from the "core" process.

Comment: If there is a way to spawn the workers such that they inherit the global namespace of the core process at spawn time, that would work just fine.

Comment: `multiprocessing` *should* handle those imports for you. You may be doing something wrong. (With how confusing the `multiprocessing` module is, it's pretty easy to get things wrong.)

Comment: @user2357112 I posted an edit that shows the code I use to spawn the workers -- could you take a look?

Comment: "is there a way to build a list of all of the functions called inside of it, without executing it" - maybe you need to take a look into `functools.partial`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov I use partial a lot -- what would its application be here?  I thought the intent was to effectively assign arguments of a function to constants and make a new callable with fewer arguments.